# How do I get a stable 15V signal without a variable power supply?

Tags: wheatstone-bridge

I'm studying mechanical engineering (inb4 easy major), so my knowledge of EE is limited and sequestered to blind application.

I need a stable 15V supply for a wheatstone-bridge strain sensing circuit, and I can't use a power supply (too bulky). I wanted to use a battery bank and just step up the voltage, but I'm given to understand they output some sort of PWM signal, not a stable DC signal. My thought was to use a boost converter to step up to 18V, and then use some kind of LC smoothing filter to get a stable 15V. Is this a bad idea? How would you guys approach this? Is there any sort of cheap IC package that will do all of this for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a wall wart

Comment: A decent boost converter filters its output.  Without telling us what amount of ripple voltage is acceptable, we can't tell you whether you need to use the LDO after a boost converter.

Comment: You must define resolution in mV to let us know what noise you can tolerate. #15 is the best https://www.hbm.com/en/7163/wheatstone-bridge-circuit/

Comment: Luckily, you no longer need to be an expert PhD physicist! Today, you can use a programmable Josephson voltage standard (PJVS)! Through a computer interface, you tell the PJVS to generate any voltage you want -- including exactly 15 V! The whole system consists of just one simple little junction chip (you don't even need that cheap IC package!) that is mounted at the end of a rod for immersion into liquid helium. Well, there is a small rack of added electronics. But if you want a stable 15 V, that's it! NIST replaced all their battery chemistry crap with these babies! Or do you have any specs?

Answer (score 1):

Use a boost to get 18V to 20V then use a linear regulator like LM7815 to make a stable 15V

Low drop-out linear regulators "LDOs" are best avoided, the compromises made to achieve the low headroom operation can lead to surprises like oscillations or unexpected pass-bands.

Answer (score 0):

" I can't use a power supply (too bulky)", I suppose you think about a big laboratory power supply ?

Depending on requirements, it exists tiny AC/DC converters ( [a 1"x1" cube for 3W](https://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/show/ac-dc-power-supplies/encapsulated-modules/tmps-03/1/) ).
You can find them in various sizes/formats encapsulated or not: [Traco Power AC/DC](https://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/category/ac-dc-power-supplies/), [Mean Well AC/DC](https://www.meanwell.com/productSeries.aspx?i=18&c=6#tag-6-18).

If you want to power the system from a battery, you can use non-isolated DC/DC converters: [Traco Power DC/DC](https://www.tracopower.com/products/browse-by-category/category/dc-dc-converters/), [Mean Well DC/DC](https://www.meanwell.com/productSeries.aspx?i=12&c=7#tag-7-12).

If you prefer to make your own power supply, you can check for example [Texas Instrument Power Management integrated circuits](http://www.ti.com/power-management/overview.html).